# Regex: Extract url parameters

Tags: regex, url, url-parameters

I am looking for a regex to extract URL params. My current solution is this:

```
(?i)key(?-i)=([^&]+)
```

but it fails on some of the tests below.

Lines where I want to match

```
cool=13&nice=zz&key=value&polo=0
Key=value&cool=13&nice=zz&polo=0
cool=13&nice=zz&polo=0&key=value
```

Lines I don't want to match it

```
cool=13&nice=zz&myKey=value&polo=0
```

Comment: Depending on which language you are using with this, it may already be available to you without regex.

Comment: If lookbehind is available then use: [`(?<=&|^)(?i)key(?-i)=[^&]*`](https://regex101.com/r/kfUIJZ/1)

Comment: oh, nice, I wasn't aware to lookbehind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL parsing routines are available in many languages and it is recommended to use them as first choice.

However if you want to use regex for some reason, here is a lookbehind regex that you may use:

```
(?<=&|^)(?i)key(?-i)=[^&]*
```

Here `(?<=&|^)` is a lookbehind assertion that makes sure that there is a `&` or line start before matching `key`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kfUIJZ/1/)

Comment: `(?-i)` can be safely removed. `[^&]` will not be affected by the case insensitive modifier.

Comment: Yes, Agreed Wiktor.